# Windows 8 app with Flash

Tags: flash, windows-8

Is it possible to load a Flash SWF file inside a Windows 8 app?

I can't seem to find any information on it and when I try to load it just basically through the default.html like I would on a web page, nothing loads.

Basically all I want to do is load a preexisting Flash file, but have it wrapped in the whole tile interface, etc.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you are talking about Windows Store/Metro app the answer is a no. Unless if somebody ports implementation of Flash player to WinRT you wouldn't be able to play swf files in the metro app.

Comment: Thanks.  Doing some reading around the forums, I have found a couple that address this as well.  Seems like Microsoft dropped the ball on this one.